# Индекс массива по значению

Tags: массивы, php

Допустим, есть массив

```
array(
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'a', 'b', 'c'
);
```

Как по значению узнать индекс? Например, из значения **a** должно вернуть **10**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 6):

```
array_search("а", $arr);
```